# Natural earth tiles are not detailed enough

Tags: tiles, mapbox, d3

I am new to GIS, but I have been using the following set of tiles in some of my D3 applications:

```
.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.natural-earth-2/
```

The issue with these tiles is that they are not too 'deep', by which I mean no tiles are displayed at higher zoom levels. Is there another natural earth set of tiles that allows for higher zoom levels?

Purely as an FYI, if needed, this is how I fetch my tiles:

```
image.enter().append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "http://" + "abc"[d[1] % 3] + ".tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.natural-earth-2/" + d[2] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[1] + ".png"; })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d[0] * 256; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d[1] * 256; })
    .attr("width", 256)
    .attr("height", 256);
```

Answer (score 2):

Natural Earth tiles are made from these public datasets https://www.naturalearthdata.com/. The most detailed data are at scale 1:10 million. For more detailed maps you need data from some other sources. One good candidate is OpenStreetMap.

Comment: Hello - thanks for your comment. I have tried to identify another data source for a detailed terrain tileset but am so far not making any progress. I could definitely not find what I am looking for at OpenStreetMap.

Answer (score 1):

[Mapbox Streets](https://www.mapbox.com/maps/streets/) and [Mapbox Outdoors](https://www.mapbox.com/maps/outdoors/) both include terrain hillshading and go though to high zoom levels.

If either of these aren't exactly the style you're after, you could use Mapbox Studio to create a new style that looks like Natural Earth 2, but with support for high zooms using the Mapbox Streets tileset. See how you can tweak the terrain style at https://blog.mapbox.com/new-in-studio-dynamic-hillshading-2027c77781d8.

The [Mapbox Designer Maps](https://www.mapbox.com/designer-maps/) might be suitable alternatives too.

They are all accessible as 256x256 XYZ tiles using the API documented at https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#retrieve-raster-tiles-from-styles